# While will a div with min-height: 100% not expand when it's content grows to large

Tags: html, css

Here is a codepen with the general problem:
https://codepen.io/tgreen/pen/PJbPEB

```
.canvas {
   padding: 40px;
   max-width: 1170px;
   width: 100%;
   align-self: center;
   min-height: 100%;
   background: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

I want the canvas to start at a minimum height of 100% so it fills the whole browser window, but if its content grows larger than that it should also grow to contain that. Basically I want that white box to reach the bottom at all times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the percentage values to vh based values,

[Here is a working demo](https://codepen.io/delovan99/pen/oGYjRE)

This is because percentage values are relative to parent container, and what you are trying to achieve is relative to viewport size (you can simply replace the `height: 100%` of the `html, body` attributes by a `min-height: 100%`, but the canevas won't take 100% of the page if the red box is small, it will just adapt to it.

Answer (score 0):

just simply remove height property from body, html

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

Comment: He wants the canvas to start at a minimum height of 100%.

Comment: ah, my bad, then .canvas should have min-height: 100vh;